# PS1 only outputs the PS1 string not proper values

Tags: bash, ps1

I'm using iTerm2 on MacOS Sierra. I try to edit the `PS1` in variable `.bash_profile` to be
`PS1="\h:\W \u \$"`
but in terminal I get the promp
`\h:\W \u \$` instead of `Simon:~ simon $`

Any ideas why it behaves like this?

Comment: Did you try setting `PS1` in `.bashrc` instead?

Comment: I tried in prompt: `export PS1="\h:\W \u \$"`. Same result as before.

Comment: Maybe you are using something else than bash? Double check with: env | grep SHELL

Comment: Ah it outputs `SHELL=/bin/zsh` wanna have `SHELL=/bin/bash` how to make it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iTerm2 you can use bash instead of zsh by setting inside profile settings

`iTerm2 -> Profiles -> Choose Profile on left -> Command: /bin/bash`

[image]

Simply tell iTerm2 to use arbitrary **Command** instead of **Login shell**.

Comment: .oOo. Cool! Have fun with iTerm2! .oOo.